# Generic method where T implements Interface<T>

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface

I'm trying to create a generic data retrieval process. What I have currently works, but there is a part of it that doesn't seem right and I'm hoping there is a better way to accomplish it.

So the idea is that I have classes for each table in the database, here is an example of a class:

```
public class CMCGRGRGROUP : IFacetsObject<CMCGRGRGROUP>
{
    public int GRGR_CK { get; set; }
    public string GRGR_NAME { get; set; }
    public string GRGR_ADDR1 { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<CMCGRGRGROUP> ToObject(DataTable table)
    {
        return table.AsEnumerable().Select(row =>
        {
            return new CMCGRGRGROUP
            {
                GRGR_CK = Convert.ToInt32(row["GRGR_CK"]),
                GRGR_NAME = row["GRGR_NAME"].ToString(),
                GRGR_ADDR1 = row["GRGR_ADDR1"].ToString()
            };
        });
    }
}
```

You'll notice that the class implements an interface of its own type. The interface simply defines a method called `ToObject`, which is used to convert a datatable to a class of that particular type:

```
public interface IFacetsObject<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> ToObject(DataTable obj);
}
```

Now, here is the method that I am using to execute a query:

```
public IEnumerable<T> ExecuteQuery<T>(string sql, IFacetsObject<T> obj) where T : new()
{
    using (var conn = new AseConnection(_conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        var cmd = new AseCommand(sql, conn);

        var dt = new DataTable();
        var da = new AseDataAdapter(sql, conn);
        da.Fill(dt);                

        return obj.ToObject(dt); //this is the interface method
    }
}
```

**So the main question is:**
How can the generic method know that T should implement `IFacetsObject<T>`? That way I don't have to pass `IFacetsObject<T>` as a parameter. Ideally, I could change the return line to be something like this:

```
return T.ToObject(dt);
```

And call it like this:

```
var result = ExecuteQuery<CMCGRGRGROUP>(sql).Take(5);
```

Instead of like this:

```
var result = ExecuteQuery<CMCGRGRGROUP>(sql, new CMCGRGRGROUP()).Take(5);
```

I'll admit that I'm not terribly familiar with generics yet so there may be something within the implementation that isn't right.

Comment: I see you use the orkish variable naming convention

Comment: Yes, they are terrible - unfortunately didn't name the db tables just trying to keep the names consistent.

Comment: You can't inherit from an interface, on a sidenote. (Interfaces are _implemented_, behaviour / implementations are _inherited_)

Comment: @sehe Technically interface can *inherit* from other interfaces.

Comment: Yes thanks that makes sense, updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @Servy _"inherit"_ is a little misleading. Consider explicit _implementations_ - they defy the rules of inheritance.

Comment: Be careful with this paradigm/pattern. You're creating the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx) which is a slippery slope.

Comment: @Gusdor First off, I was discussing interface inheritance, to which explicit implementations don't really apply.  Second, explicit interface implementations *don't* defy the rules of inheritance.

Comment: Thanks for the link @DavidHaney, I can see where a future developer may have difficulty initially understanding and/or implementing the pattern - and it would be possible to have unintended consequences but not implementing the interface "correctly" according to the pattern that it in use. That being said, this particular project shouldn't need much maintenance to this portion (adding new classes for example), so I think simplifying the areas that are more likely to change (queries) is more beneficial down the road. I will be sure to include helpful comments for the class definitions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a constraint on your ExecuteQuery method. You already have one: requiring that T be newable. You'd declare it like:

```
public IEnumerable<T> ExecuteQuery<T>(string sql, IFacetsObject<T> obj) 
  where T : IFacetsObject<T>, new()
{
    using (var conn = new AseConnection(_conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        var cmd = new AseCommand(sql, conn);

        var dt = new DataTable();
        var da = new AseDataAdapter(sql, conn);
        da.Fill(dt);                

        return obj.ToObject(dt); //this is the interface method
    }
}
```

So it now knows T is an `IFacetsObject<T>`. You could now do:

```
public IEnumerable<T> ExecuteQuery<T>(string sql) 
  where T : IFacetsObject<T>, new()
{
    using (var conn = new AseConnection(_conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        var cmd = new AseCommand(sql, conn);

        var dt = new DataTable();
        var da = new AseDataAdapter(sql, conn);
        da.Fill(dt);                

        return new T().ToObject(dt); //this is the interface method
    }
}
```

Which IMO is still pretty ugly.

**EDIT Response:**

Note that you cannot call T.ToObject - an interface cannot define a static method. The workaround is the use of new to create a new instance of T and call the instance method.

Comment: It may be ugly, but I think this is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

You need a generic constraint on your interface.  Declare it like this:

```
public interface IFacetsObject<T> where T : IFacetsObject<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> ToObject(DataTable obj);
}
```

In order to get this to work, you also have to change your declaration like this:

```
public IEnumerable<T> ExecuteQuery<T>(string sql, IFacetsObject<T> obj) 
    where T : IFacetsObject<T>, new()
```

Comment: The question is asking about the generic method I think, not how to constrain the interface